# How do I create a new page template inside sfSimpleCMSplugin?

Tags: symfony1

I have and old version of sfsimplecmsplugin running inside of Symfony v1. I need to create new page templates but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

Did you read the [doc](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfSimpleCMSPlugin/0_7_3?tab=plugin_readme)?

> The plugin is bundled with a few basic templates, but you will definitely need to add your own templates.
>
> CMS templates are files located under the `sfSimpleCMS` module's `templates/` directory, with a name ending with `Template.php`. A template must include the `sfSimpleCMS` helper group and call the `include_editor_tools()` helper at the bottom.

So basically, you create a new file called `/apps/frontend/modules/sfSimpleCMS/templates/myPageTemplate.php` and you copy/paste [**this file**](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/plugins/sfSimpleCMSPlugin/trunk/modules/sfSimpleCMS/templates/simplePageTemplate.php) inside as a starting point for your new template.